# Github custom action result varies with different use style

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a github repo like this, files with same name have same content.

```
├── .github
│   ├── actions
│   │   └── hello-world
│   │       └── action.yml
│   └── workflows
│       └── main.yml
├── action.yml
└── goodbye.sh
```

The code in `action.yml` given in follow, which is copied from official tutorial.

```yaml
name: "Hello World"
description: "Greet to my little friend"
inputs:
  who-to-greet:
    description: "who to greet"
    required: true
    default: "World"
outputs:
  random-number:
    description: "Random number"
    value: ${{ steps.random-number-generator.outputs.random-number }}
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - run: echo Hello ${{ inputs.who-to-greet }}.
      shell: bash
    - id: random-number-generator
      run: echo "random-number=$(echo $RANDOM)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      shell: bash
    - run: echo "${{ github.action_path }}" >> $GITHUB_PATH
      shell: bash
    - run: goodbye.sh
      shell: bash
```

Then I try to use it in two different ways, first by `{owner}/{repo}@{ref}`, second by `./path/to/dir`, however only second way can display `random-number` normally. Why?

```yaml
on:
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  hello_world:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: say hello to my little firend
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - id: foo
        uses: chaoqunya/hello-world-composite-action@v1
        with:
          who-to-greet: "Chaos"
      - run: echo random-number ${{ steps.foo.outputs.random-number }} test
        shell: bash
      - id: bar
        uses: ./.github/actions/hello-world
        with:
          who-to-greet: "Chaos"
      - run: echo random-number ${{ steps.bar.outputs.random-number }} test
        shell: bash
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first uses statement has @v1 attached to it, which means you are using the version from that tag.

Delete (including the remote!), recreate and push the tag again, or use @branch-name during testing.